# AVMutableComposition: small jump between video segments when playing

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm using `AVMutableComposition` to play a video which is split in different continuous files. However, when playing, there is a small jump (short black screen) between 2 consecutive segments.

Is there any way to prevent that?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class KLMasterPlayerViewController: KLPlayerViewController {

    let comp:AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem!

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.initComp()
        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.comp)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

    }

    private func initComp() {

        let segments = MasterVideo.sharedInstance.videoSegments

        var insertedTime:Double = 0.0

        for segment in segments {

            do {

                let asset = segment.getURLAsset()

                try comp.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,asset!.duration), ofAsset: asset!, atTime: CMTimeMake(Int64(insertedTime * 10000), 10000))

                insertedTime += segment.getDuration()

            } catch {

            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: probably your video containing a second gap before play just check.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no, the video files are all fine with no black at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: Swift wasn't calculating the duration of my video assets properly. For each one of them, there was a different of 1 image.
By forcing the video segments duration, that was fine and flawless.

Glad it's solved!

Many thanks to vaibhav for trying to help.